# What to do with helpful link-only answers pointing to a code snippet that does not have a specific license?

Tags: support, link-only-answers, licensing

A certain question asking how to achieve something with jQuery UI has an answer that points to a code snippet. The code is helpful, albeit long (400+ lines). It does not mention a license, but it does mention copyright:

> Copyright (c) 2009 *author name* (*author website*)

Does the code now fall under the *cc by-sa 3.0* license, and can I copy the code into the answer? Or must the answer be deleted?

I can't ask the author to (re)license the code, he was last seen in 2009.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was *definitely* written by the same person who posted the answer? If you're certain about that, I'd say that the intent is clear—they meant to contribute it as part of their Stack Overflow answer. In which case, yes, it falls under our standard license.

You could leave the copyright comment there, just to avoid friction. It serves no legal purpose anyway.

If the code was *not* written by the person who posted the answer, or there's reason to doubt that fact, then unfortunately I'd say the answer has to be removed. Or expanded into a non-link-only answer, if you're willing to invest the time to do so. Good answers don't *necessarily* require code. You can *describe* the solution using gōd ol Ænglisc words.

If not, and the link is truly useful, perhaps flag a moderator to convert the answer to a comment. Link-only comments are okay. Not great, but okay.

Comment: After further inspection I learned that it's a modified version of code written by someone else, but with the copyright information left intact. I'll err on the side of caution and flag it to have it converted to a comment.

Comment: @Stijn given that you asked here at meta, consider supplying your flag message with the link to this meta question. Per my experience, moderators tend to appreciate when notified that there is meta discussion about flagged post

Comment: @gnat I've done exactly that :)

Comment: I think you could just as well argue that the fact that the poster *didn't* originally put the code in their SO answer implies that they **did not** want to put it under the CC license.

Comment: I thought the only language accepted on the SO is the modern English...